# is there an Angular event like ngDoneCheck?

Tags: angular

## Problem

I want any way to know that angular has finished rendering *ngFor directives (EDIT:) when a new element is added to the array it is tracking dynamically, and after ngAfterViewInit.

## Example

an example of my problem: I have an array of 2 things. They are generated into content editable p tags with ngFor.

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <p 
      *ngFor="let el of myArray" 
       contenteditable="true"
       (keydown.enter)="addNewP()"
    >{{el}}</p>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myArray = ["first", "second"];
  addNewP(){
    this.myArray.splice(1, 0, "in the middle");
  }
}
```

How can I get an async notification that angular is done rendering so that I can put focus on the "in the middle" element, after the user presses enter?

## My current solution

Currently I'm using a custom directive from https://www.codementor.io/yomateo/auto-focus-with-angular-7-the-directive-osfcl7rrv:

```typescript
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocusNew]'
})
export class FocusNewDirective implements AfterContentInit{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef//tiny side note: angular warns extensively against this, should i avoid it?
    ) { }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    },0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `last` value provided by `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arr; let lastReached = last">
    <div>{{ last ? myFunction() }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: shoot, this doesn't work if the element is in the middle of the array, it seams to always resolve to the lowest p element

Comment: Question was get to know that for loop has stopped rendering and that will be when lop reaches the end. So we don’t need to check middle element of the array.

Comment: Oh, wow, yeah you're right, I was thinking angular wouldn't call this function if the addNewP() method is called since the last element wouldn't be re-rendered, but this function is called for some reason i don't quite get. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`OnInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit) lifecycle hook in your directive. Also make sure to use the directive in the template like this `appFocusNew = ""`. Otherwise `ngOnInit` may not be fired.

Directive:

```typescript
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appFocusNew]'
})
export class FocusNewDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }

}
```

Template:

```typescript
<p 
  *ngFor="let el of myArray" 
    contenteditable="true"
    (keydown.enter)="addNewP()"
    appFocusNew = ""> 
    {{el}}
</p>
```

Working [DEMO here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvbbmq-directive-sample-forcus-47eu3n?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngAfterViewChecked in your component, [link](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewChecked). This will be invoked every time your html changes are checked.

In this way once your array is modified and your html changes, ngAfterViewChecked will be called and you can apply the focus.

```
     export class AppComponent implements AfterViewChecked{
      myArray = ["first", "second"];
      ngAfterViewChecked(){
       // put focus here.
      }
    }
```

Comment: AfterViewInit doesn't seam to work when the enter key is pressed, which adds a new element to the array that angular builds the template on

Comment: sorry i missed that you're adding new element in the array, use ngAfterViewChecked instead. Modifying my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
    <p
      #pList
      *ngFor="let el of myArray"
      contenteditable="true"
      (keydown.enter)="addNewP()"
    >
      {{ el }}
    </p>
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren("pList") protected pList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  myArray = ["first", "second"];
  addNewP() {
    this.myArray.splice(1, 0, "in the middle");
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pList.first.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using life cycle events? https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence